# TortoiseSVN import

Tags: svn, import, tortoisesvn

My developer gave me a compressed file for the whole project from his Subversion working copy.

I uncompressed that file and used TortoiseSVN import to put it into my repository which I host with projectlocker (an SVN-hosting provider).

I want to know:

1. I want to view the files and the code that has changed since the last revision. After doing the import, the latest revision is at 8. I want to see what files and code has changed between revision number 8 and revision number 7 and maybe able to compare all of it upto revision number 1.

Can I do this?

2. How do I view these changes in projectlocker (or if it's the similar process with every SVN host provider)?

Comment: I am somehow confused if import was the right thing to do.... When i right clicked the torotoisesvn, the  import option seemed the best option to me to get the project into the repository. Now i am not sure if i messed up things... can i still view the changes?  I am first time tortoisesvn user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your developer simply compressed all the files from his working copy you will not get any history with the files.

If you want to export the entire Subversion history you need to use the *dump* and *load* svnadmin commands, see *[Moving a Subversion Repository to Another Server](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm)*

To get the svnadmin command, you may need a Subversion server to be installed. Since you're using Windows VisualSVN maybe what you need is http://www.visualsvn.com/server/.

Yet another option is simply to access the same Subversion repository your developer is using.

Once you have the repository TortoiseSVN's Show Log (right click) will show you the changed files between revisions. If you click on a folder you see all the changes in the hierarchy. You can then drill down and diff the individual files.

Comment: So then can i undo the import and ask the developer to update the repository from is working copy?   Can i undo the import so that the latest revision is back to revision no. 7? How to do it?

Comment: Also, the compressed file he sent me does include the .svn version files.... so do we still lose the versioning history?

Comment: +1 because @user481913 needs a backup of repositiory or onlineaccess to see history

Comment: importing is equal to copying all the files and folders into your a working copy, adding all files, and committing.  In subversion you can't un-do a commit.  Did you have anything in your repository before you imported the files you received?  If not then simply start fresh.  If you did that is more complicated, what did you have in your repository?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is not remote accessable, @Guy-s "using a backup of the repository" works perfectly as long @user481913 only wants to read.

**What if @user481913 wants to check in changes?**

I am not sure if there is a waIf to synchronize to svn-repositories.

Since I am in a similar situation I am using the [Git sourcecontrolsystem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) that works offline and can syncronise with a Subversion repository. There is also a [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).